# Why do eyes water in response to particular emotions?

Tags: eyes, human-eye

It is common for people to experience very moving situations (sad movies, etc) and have a physical reaction to it (such as crying). I am curious about how emotions can physically lead to the act of crying. Why/how does this happen? What is the mechanism?

Comment: Can you please clarify this question, and also support your assertion with a little bit of the background reading you've done about it?

Comment: @anongoodnurse Many questions about biology are so obvious from the human perspective, that no reading should be asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we are sad, our emotions are in an overdrive and the parasympathetic nervous system triggers lacrimation i.e. tears, and we cry.

Comment: Great succinct answer for a vague topic.

Comment: You're only answering the proximal (physiologic) why, i.e. the mechanism. What about the distal (evolutionary) why?